# Partitioning a USB drive

Tags: usb, partitioning

I have a usb drive formatted in NTFS and was wondering if there was a way to partition it, I have looked in disk management and I am unable to partition it that way, is there any other way of partitioning?

I believe that it is impossible to partition my usb drive, possibly because it is too small (1gb) or any other reasons but thank you for the help.

I have got it so I have two partitions, but I cannot label one of them
[image]

I am trying to partiotion the s: drive

Comment: If it is NTFS it is already formatted which means it is already partitioned so you cannot parttition it further unless you delete the NTFS partition. This question has nothing to do with programming though!

Comment: I was thinking there was a way to do it through cmd prompt. Would there be a way it I put it into FAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do what I wanted to do through virtual hard disks

Virtual hard disks can be created through the disk management under actions

I would also like to thank howtogeek for providing the knowledge to create a bat file to make attaching virtual disks easier
The howtogeek bat file help can be found here http://www.howtogeek.com/51174/mount-and-unmount-a-vhd-file-in-windows-explorer-via-a-right-click/

Thank you everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can run `DISKPART` in an Administrator's Command Prompt, then use the `LIST`, `SELECT` and `DELETE`, followed by `CREATE` commands.

To get an Administrator Command Prompt, click

```
Start
All Programs
Accessories
Right-click Command prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
```

!!! WARNING - YOU WILL LOSE ALL DATA ON YOUR USB DRIVE !!!

Comment: When you are creating the partition it asks you to specify a size, but gives no units, what is the units of this size?

Comment: Have a look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: It keeps on saying access is denied

Comment: That is for creating a linux partition, not a partition.

Comment: GParted can also create Windows partitions - which Windows itself seems not to be able to.

Comment: Please look at my original statement, I have updated it.